# Reload screen when react-native app is re-opened

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

In a react-native application, when we click on Home button the application is minimized. If after that I click on the application then application is resumed where it was minimized last.  I want to refresh the last open screen every time that the application is maximized. What should I do to achieve this?

I tried `{useIsFocused}` from `@react-navigation/native` and I also tried

```
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
     alert('focus')
});
```

But it's not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please change you question to "Listen for background/foreground app state in react native" or something similar so that it will be easier for other users to search. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Appstate is what you're looking for. Change `componentDidMount` to `useEffect` and `state` to `useState` if required. More info [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate)

```
import {
    AppState
} from 'react-native';

constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
       appState: AppState.currentState
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}

_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
            this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
            nextAppState === 'active'
        ) {
            //Todo: Reload task here
        }
        this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
};
```